# dynamic links in .so file in a pip wheel not being found

Tags: python, package, setuptools

The structure of my package is following:

```sh
.
├── setup.py
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_package.py
│   ├── _my_package.so
│   ├── libmy_package.so
│   ├── libmy_package.so.1
│   └── libmy_package.so.1.0.0
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'my_package': ['_my_package.so', 'libmy_package.so.1', 
                                 'libmy_package.so', 'libmy_package.so.1.0.0']}
)
```

When I do `pip wheel .`, it is being built without a problem. Also an installation in a separated Docker environment runs smoothly.

However, when I try to do `python -c "import my_package"`, I encounter always the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/my_package/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .my_package import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/my_package/my_package.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _my_package
ImportError: libmy_package.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I do `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/my_package/`, I see this:

```
__init__.py  __pycache__  _my_package.so  my_package.py  libmy_package.so  libmy_package.so.1  libmy_package.so.1.0.0
```

Therefore I have tried `export LD_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/my_package`. After that, the import runs smoothly.

Am I doing something wrong that I have to set the `LD_CONFIG_PATH` manually? Is there a way to avoid setting this path (as it can be a bit dangerous)? Something in `setup.py` or some wheel parameters? Is there a way to change the `rpath` of `my_package.so` during the wheel creation? Asking about ways to do it through `pip` or through `setup.py`, without other tools (changing the `rpath` after, using `auditwheel`).

Comment: Use `auditwheel` to properly include third party libs.

Comment: Yes, updating it with `auditwheel` would solve the situation. As would changing the `RPATH` of `_my_package.so` (which is the way I have solved it). I was more interested in the question if there is a way to do it through `setup.py`.

Comment: Well, you can invoke `auditwheel` or `patchelf` from a custom command that is registered in the setup script, but no declarative way IIRC if that's what you are looking for.